# Spark SQL scenario not giving the correct results

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df as below:

1. Where mobile number is `different`:

   ```
   |applicantkey|     first_reg_date|utmcontent| latest_signin_date|mobilenumber|
    +------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
    |        1234|2021-01-03 06:05:43|   Android|2021-01-03 06:05:43|         987|
    |        1234|2021-04-03 07:05:43|   Android|2021-10-03 06:05:43|         986|
    +------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
   ```
2. Where mobile number is `same`:

   ```
   |applicantkey|     first_reg_date|utmcontent| latest_signin_date|mobilenumber|
    +------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
    |        1234|2021-01-03 06:05:43|   Android|2021-01-03 06:05:43|         987|
    |        1234|2021-04-03 07:05:43|   Android|2021-10-03 06:05:43|         987|
    +------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
   ```

Now, I want to get the `min` of `first_reg_date` and `max` of `latest_signin_date` and replace the values of those two columns in the dataset. So my expected output should be like below:

```
+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
|applicantkey|first_reg_date     |utmcontent|latest_signin_date |mobilenumber|
+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
|1234        |2021-01-03 06:05:43|Android   |2021-10-03 06:05:43|987         |
|1234        |2021-01-03 06:05:43|Android   |2021-10-03 06:05:43|986         |

+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
```

I tried the below query but it gives output as shown below:

```
spark.sql(
    "select applicantkey,min(first_reg_date) first_reg_date,utmcontent,max(latest_signin_date) latest_signin_date,mobilenumber from df group by applicantkey,utmcontent,mobilenumber").show(truncate=False)

+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
|applicantkey|first_reg_date     |utmcontent|latest_signin_date |mobilenumber|
+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
|1234        |2021-01-03 06:05:43|Android   |2021-01-03 06:05:43|987         |
|1234        |2021-04-03 07:05:43|Android   |2021-10-03 06:05:43|986         |
+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
```

**`AND`**

```
+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
|applicantkey|first_reg_date     |utmcontent|latest_signin_date |mobilenumber|
+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
|1234        |2021-01-03 06:05:43|Android   |2021-10-03 06:05:43|987         |
+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
```

Where the second output is correct but the first output is wrong.

So, I tried below way and it is helping me get the correct results but I am getting duplicates when the mobile number is the same:

```
df1 = spark.sql(
    "select applicantkey,min(first_reg_date) first_reg_date, max(latest_signin_date) latest_signin_date from df group by applicantkey")
df2 = spark.sql("select applicantkey,utmcontent,mobilenumber from df")
df3 = df1.join(df2, "applicantkey", "left_outer")
df3.show(truncate=False)  

+------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+------------+
|applicantkey|first_reg_date     |latest_signin_date |utmcontent|mobilenumber|
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+------------+
|1234        |2021-01-03 06:05:43|2021-10-03 06:05:43|Android   |987         |
|1234        |2021-01-03 06:05:43|2021-10-03 06:05:43|Android   |987         |
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------+------------+
```

I don't wanna use `DISTINCT()` at the end. So, What am I exactly doing wrong?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question better, Do you want to find the `min(first_reg_date)` and `max(latest_signin_date)` for every applicant or every applicant, mobilenumber combination?
You can apply [`first`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#first) or [`last`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#last)  as dummy aggregation to select  `utmcontent` and `mobilenumber`, but again it depends on what you want exactly.

Comment: for the same `applicantkey` records I want both `min(first_reg_date)` and `max(latest_signin_date)` and rest values should be picked up as it is.

Answer (score -1):

Going by your comment, you want to select the `min(first_reg_date)` and `max(latest_signin_date)` per `applicantkey` for all rows in your dataframe. You can do this via [`window functions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html).
We will partition the dataframe by `applicantkey` and for each row in this partition, we will fill the value of `min(first_reg_date)` and `max(latest_signin_date)`; we will leave the other columns as-is.

### Minimally Working Example

```
from datetime import datetime

from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = [(1234,datetime.strptime("2021-01-03 06:05:43", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"Android",datetime.strptime("2021-01-03 06:05:43", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),987),
         (1234,datetime.strptime("2021-04-03 07:05:43", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"Android",datetime.strptime("2021-10-03 06:05:43", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),986),
         (1234,datetime.strptime("2021-01-03 06:05:43", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"Android",datetime.strptime("2021-01-03 06:05:43", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),987),
         (1234,datetime.strptime("2021-04-03 07:05:43", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"Android",datetime.strptime("2021-01-03 06:05:43", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),987),
  ]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("applicantkey",IntegerType(),True),
    StructField("first_reg_date",TimestampType(),True),
    StructField("utmcontent",StringType(),True),
    StructField("latest_signin_date", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("mobilenumber", IntegerType(), True),
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
```

**Windowing Logic**

```
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("applicantkey")
df.withColumn("first_reg_date", F.min(F.col("first_reg_date")).over(window_spec)).withColumn("latest_signin_date", F.max(F.col("latest_signin_date")).over(window_spec)).show()
```

**Output**

```
+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
|applicantkey|     first_reg_date|utmcontent| latest_signin_date|mobilenumber|
+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
|        1234|2021-01-03 06:05:43|   Android|2021-10-03 06:05:43|         987|
|        1234|2021-01-03 06:05:43|   Android|2021-10-03 06:05:43|         986|
|        1234|2021-01-03 06:05:43|   Android|2021-10-03 06:05:43|         987|
|        1234|2021-01-03 06:05:43|   Android|2021-10-03 06:05:43|         987|
+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------+
```

PS. When asking questions in the future do include a minimally working example.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help @snithish. But, can you read my question again? In my question I have mentioned what I am expecting and by using my snippet what exactly I am getting. I am still not sure what do you exactly mean by "minimally working example". I have mentioned 2 different approaches which worked for me but not the way I am looking for. Also, using your solution I won't be able to resolve the last part of my question which is `avoiding distinct()`.

Comment: Also, your code is not up to the mark. It will lead to duplicate columns.

Comment: @whatsinthename I understand that you are trying to apply an aggregation and also want the values of the non aggregated columns included. However, you don't say how to resolve the ambiguity. For example, after finding the `min(first_reg_date)` and `max(latest_signin_date)` when you are looking at the `mobilenumber` column you have two possible options (986, 987), which one would you want and why?

Comment: @whatsinthename also what do you expect incase of two unique values in `utmcontent` column like `android` and `ios`?